# Div for not working in new versions of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having my code as below

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
<div class="comments_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <p class="lead"><%= comment.body %></p>
        <p><small>Submitted <strong><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</strong> by <%= comment.user.name %></small></p>
    </div>
```

I am using Rails v5.0,  Ruby 2.3.1 versions. 
When I run the application using "rails s" command.

It throws the following error.

> Error:RecordTagHelper.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.
We all know rails5 have been released recently.

The code which was in action view in the older versions of rails<5.0 was removed..

So we need to add a gem called ‘record_tag_helper’

IN MY CASE
I am having my view code as below

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
<div class="comments_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <p class="lead"><%= comment.body %></p>
        <p><small>Submitted <strong><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</strong> by <%= comment.user.name %></small></p>
    </div>
```

when i run the application in new version of rails it wont work

why its not working??

RecordTagHelper consists of code that was formerly a part of
"ActionView".
but has been removed from core in Rails 5.

Solution

we need to add  gem ‘record_tag_helper’, ‘~> 1.0’ to our gem file and run bundle install.

This gem is provided to ensure projects that use functionality from
ActionView::Helpers::RecordTagHelper
have an appropriate upgrade path.

Answer (score 0):

From Apidock,

> div_for(record, *args, &block) public
>
> Produces a wrapper DIV element with id and class parameters that relate to the specified Active Record object.

The first parameter has to be a ActiveRecord object. In your code, you're passing `Item` to div_for. It should instead be `item` which is the valid AR object here. You haven't posted the whole block. Anyway, try this.

```
<%= div_for(item) do %>
  <div class="itemss_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <p class="lead">
        <%= item.body %>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have updated my whole code. can you check that now. I have tried your suggestion its still the same.

Comment: What error are you getting? `Error:RecordTagHelper` or any other error?

Comment: Hi Arun, I have found the solution. See my answer.